# Is it possible to get the size of a string for the function fread()

Tags: c, string, pointers, sizeof, fread

I need to get the size of a string to pass to the function read()
below is the code that I have tried to implement finding the size of the string using the function size of but it doesn't work

```
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    char *string;
    FILE *fptr;

   // use appropriate location if you are using MacOS or Linux
   fptr = fopen("program4.txt","r");

   if(fptr == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!");
      exit(1);
   }
    
    
    fread(string, /*issuse */sizeof(string), 1, fptr);
       printf("%s\n", string);
    
    fclose(fptr);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't allocate any space for a string in the first place. There's nothing to get the size of.

Comment: That is generally not possible in a generic way. If you do not have any idea or any limitation how long a string is supposed to be, you must provide a buffer that is "large enough". Or you need to read your string in chunks. BTW: strings are text. Using `fread` is for reading binary data. You could use `fgets` or `fscanf` instead. You also need to tell us what a "string" is in your case. A line? A single word? The whole text file?

Comment: If you can use POSIX functions, `getline()` will allocate enough space to hold an entire line.

Answer (score 2):

- Correct use would rather be `fread(string, 1, n, fptr);` where `1` is the size in bytes of a `char` (*guaranteed* to be 1) and `n` is the allocated size of your character array. However, `fread` reads raw binary and doesn't know about things such as null termination. It reads exactly `1 * n` bytes. So it isn't suitable unless the strings in the text file are of fixed size and zero-padded... which is probably not the case here(?).
- `fgets` is likely more suitable since it stops reading upon end of line `'\n'`, so in case you have a text file with strings of variable length, each written on a line of its own, then `fgets` is the way to go.
- No matter which function you use, always check the result for errors. `fread` returns 0 upon unsuccessful read, `fgets` returns a null pointer.
- You never allocated any memory for `string` so you can't store anything in it. `sizeof` can't be used on pointers, only on arrays allocated with fixed size.
- It may be reasonable to allocate the string to some maximum allowed size in advance. For example 80 characters + 1 null terminator, or whatever makes sense for your file format.